# Does black hole entropy change as a gravitational wave passes it?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The [black hole entropy](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bekenstein-Hawking_entropy) depends on the area of the event horizon.

- Do gravitational waves change this area?
- Does the entropy increase and then decrease as the horizon stretches and contracts?

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational waves might lead to the growth of the black hole, and hence they can make the area increase. However, the area will not decrease again.

A heuristic way of thinking about this is by noticing that if a gravitational wave enters the black hole, it can never come out. Hence, it can bring energy to the black hole, but not take it away.

More technically, there is a result known as the "area theorem" which states that (more details on [Hawking & Ellis 1973 *The Large Scale Structure of Spacetime*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/large-scale-structure-of-spacetime/1E6B961EC9878EDDBBD6AC0AF031CC93), Prop. 9.2.7)

> Given a black hole $B$ in a strongly future asymptotically predictable spacetime. Suppose $R_{ab} k^a k^b \geq 0$ holds for all null vector fields $k^a$, which is the case if the [Einstein equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) hold and the [null energy condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition#Null_energy_condition) is satisfied. Under these conditions, the area of the future horizon of the black hole never decreases.

In plain English, under a few reasonable conditions (reasonable for classical matter, but violated by quantum matter), black holes can never shrink.

Comment: If the gravitational wave increases the energy of the black hole the event horizon area increases and so does entropy . But exactly what kind of energy or information has the wave brought with it to increase the entropy?

Comment: @DaveTheWave It bears gravitational energy (which is ill-defined in GR, but you can make sense of it using [appropriate definitions of mass contained in a spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity)). The information can be thought of as information about the source, for example. Gravitational waves emitted by a black hole binary carry information about the binary, which we extract at experiment like LIGO

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gravitational radiation can change the entropy of a black hole, but it will depend on the behavior of these radiation on the event horizon. One way to study these effects is by considering the example of a *shock wave*.

Imagine that I have an isolated black-hole which is at a configuration (*A*), i.e. at some given mass, charge and angular-momentum. It now emits radiation  at retarded time $u=u_0$ and then changes to a new configuration (*B*). This emitted shock wave can be modelled by the following metric
$$ds^2=(g_{ab}+\theta (u-u_0)\mathscr{L}_{\zeta}g_{ab})dx^adx^b$$
where $\zeta$ is some vector field. The idea here is that, if we start with the co-ordinate system $x^a$ at $u<u_0$, it will shift abruptly to $x^a\to x^a+\zeta^a$ for $u>u_0$. Also till linear order in $\zeta$, the space-time on either side of the shock wave is vacuum. The shock wave can also have gravitational radiation, for that one have to ensure that there is a non-zero [Weyl scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_scalar) $\psi_4$ associated to this metric.

This vector-field can be defined arbitrarily, in particular once we choose $\zeta$ to produce symmetry transformation on the horizon (i.e. $\mathscr{L}_{\zeta}g_{ab}|_H=0$ subject to some gauge conditions), we can then comment about conserved charges $Q_{\zeta}$ associated with these vector-fields. As a special case, if we consider super-translation $u\to u+T(\theta,\phi)$ on the horizon, then the charges due to the zero-modes of this transformation actually gives the Bekenstein-Hawking entropy:
$$Q^{(B)}_T-Q^{(A)}_T=\frac{T\Delta A}{4G}$$
where $\Delta A$ is change in surface area of event horizon. One possible way to define $\zeta$ and calculation of charges has been considered [in this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05703). Since the charge is essentially a *surface term*, it only depends on the behavior of $\zeta$ on the event horizon. So the outgoing radiation can have arbitrary behavior in the bulk for a given boundary condition on event horizon.

Although shock wave is an extreme scenario, the qualitative picture of the change in entropy should remain the same in case of a generic outgoing radiation